# Perl CGI To Write File

Tags: perl

I have written a Java Applet as a school project and I need a CGI file to create a file in the cgi-bin directory.  The problem is when I run the code from the browser, the code executes but my file is not created with the variable name. Nothing is created. Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use CGI;

print "content-type: text/plain\n\n";

my $q = CGI->new();
my $name = $q->param('username');
my $pw = $q->param('param');
my $bool = $q->param('bool');
my $rel = $q->param('rel');
my $ext = ".txt";
my $strt = "../cgi-bin/";
my $app = $strt . $name . $ext;

print $app;

open (FILE,'>',$app) or print "Error";
print FILE $pw . "\n";
print FILE $bool . "\n";
print FILE $rel;

close(FILE);
```

When I run the cgi it prints the $app variable and it is the correct address I want but the file is not created.  If I change the line

```
open (FILE,'>',$app) or print "Error";
```

to

```
open (FILE,'>','../cgi-bin/test.txt') or print "Error";
```

it creates the file where I want it.  Any ideas why this would happen when using the variable $app? Either way I never get Error printed to the browser.

SOLUTION:
Thanks guys for the help. When using:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

I got this error:

```
Content-type: text/html

<H1>Software error:</H1>
<PRE>Insecure dependency in open while running with -T switch
</PRE>
<P>
For help, please send mail to the webmaster (<a href="mailto:or webmaster">or webmaster</a>), giving this error message 
and the time and date of the error.
```

It seems it was not liking the -T. Once I removed that it worked.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Why you use ../cgi-bin to write into cgi-bin ?
Just use:

`open (FILE, ">$name$ext") or die $!;`

and `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to carp fatals on the browser (suitable for this debug) with file creation

Comment: Along with this use `or die $!;` instead of `or print "Error";` otherwise you won't get a message.

Answer (score 1):

`-T` is Perl's "tainted data" flag.  It stops you from doing unsafe operations with untrusted data.  Yes, your script works without the `-T` flag, but now you have a very insecure script.

If someone passes in a `username` value of `../../../../../../../../home/badguy/secret`, then you will write the username and password into `secret.txt` in badguy's home directory. `-T` prevents you from doing that.  That's why `-T` exists.